# PhantomJS webdriver error code -11 when I use uWSGI http request to launch phantomJS to grab web data

Tags: django, selenium, phantomjs, uwsgi

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tb_list_spider.py", line 42, in parse_tblist
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/phantomjs/webdriver.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.service.start()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11

Message: Service phantomjs unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -11


desired_capabilities['phantomjs.page.customHeaders.User-Agent'] = user_agent
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)   # thie line encountered exception
```

**Above is the traceback info. When I use command line way to run my code is fine, but it is not work when I use browser http request to trigger the phantomJS by uWSGI interface.**

the error code is -11,but I dont know where to find the meanning of -11. who knows the error code meaning please told me,thanks very much.

the enviroment:centos7 + python3.6.2 + phantomJS-2.1.1 + uWSGI-2.0.15 +Django-1.11.7 + selenium-3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

I already know the ansows reason,this because the uWSGI's setting.
the limit-as is the cause, annotate it will recover normal.

```
[uwsgi]
#vhost = false
http = :80
#master = true         //主进程
#vhost = true          //多站模式
#no-site = true        //多站模式时不设置入口模块和文件
workers = 10           //子进程数
#reload-mercy = 10
#vacuum = true         //退出、重启时清理文件
#max-requests = 1000
#limit-as = 512     //这个设置uwsgi内存大小的，无法启动phantomjs就是这个导致的
buffer-size = 30000
wsgi-file = /grab_web/web_api/web_api/wsgi.py
chdir = /grab_web/web_api/web_api
enable-threads = true
#single-interpreter = true
```